# Querying DBLP - ORDER BY SPARQL

Tags: sql-order-by, sparql

I am running this query

```
SELECT ?p
WHERE
{
?s ?p ?o .
}
ORDER BY ASC(?p)
```

in order to get all the `?p` available. However what I really want to do is to group the results by number of appearance say

```
p1 <- most appeared
p2
p3
```

rather than:

```
    p1
    p1
    p1
    p1
    p2
    p2
    p2
```

How can I achieve this one?

Comment: As you already said in the description, `GROUP BY ?p ORDER BY DESC(COUNT(?s))`. One question is, how you define the frequency of the predicates `?p`: The number of distinct subjects having such a triple pattern, or the total number of occurrence in the whole dataset.

Comment: @AKSW I get this error 
`Line 17, column 15: Aggregate expression not legal at this point` when I am trying your proposal. Is there something wrong with this syntax?

Comment: Which triple store or API do you use?

Comment: @AKSW you mean the endpoint? this is it `http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/snorql/`

Comment: Hm ok. It's D2R which does not support full SPARQL 1.1